# ./dist/out-tsc folder is always empty

Tags: angular7

While running "ng build" or "ng build --prod" there is no dist/out-tsc folder and even if i create one the folder remains empty. Although ng serve works fine and the site loads. 
I want to host this site but without the output folder it is worthless.

ts-config.json is as below:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Note: the project was generating all the required files until last week but stopped doing it all of a sudden.

I have also tried creating a new project and building it the result is same i.e. no out-tsc folder.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. It would be great if you share the code with us. Incase if you don't mind..

Comment: @hbamithkumara
have uploaded the code to https://github.com/mayurmaed/employee check it out and I have already ran  "_ng build_" in this and as you can see there is no /out-tsc folder

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue in two ways.

**Method 1**

Update *outputPath* in **angular.json**

```
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/out-tsc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
```

**Method 2**

Use the following command for production build

```
ng build --prod --output-path=dist/out-tsc/
```

*I've tested both methods for your code. Both are working fine.*

[image]

Comment: Does this work? If issue is still there let me know. We can have a chat.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem. As there are multiple pages that i have created and the output i get is only the index.html and related js files where as the complete application is not getting compiled to js and html. I need the static output which was getting produced untill november 20th but stopped getting generated after that. I need the static files so that they can be hosted on something like firebase. Now that these files are not getting generated I am not able to host the complete application.

Comment: But I'm able to build to that folder and serve from it. Refer Image.

Comment: I tried using "_./node_modules/.bin/tsc -project ._" which compiled and generated the static files but now the I dont know the exact structure of the dist folder and also if there is some changes that need to be made in order to make this whole thing up and running.

I have tried "_firebase serve_" to try and host the files locally instead of a server and it loads the index page but none of the links work. whereas "_ng serve_" works absolutely fine locally as it works on the dynamic files and doesnot depend on the output( i.e. static files)

Comment: Ofcourse the index page is getting generated but rest of the resources are not getting generated.

try "_ng generate component two_" and then re-compile you will se that you only find the index.html but other component(s) do not get generated at all.

nd serve will still work although but the output folder will not get any static ouput that can be hosted.